# Организация покрытия проекта тестами

Tags: php, symfony, тестирование, рефакторинг

В давнишем проекте еще на symfony 3 покрытие тестами нулевое. Сейчас это очевидно приводит к большому количеству ошибок и портит жизнь.

Как можно достаточно быстро покрыть большой проект тестами и что бы вы делали в такой ситуации?

Возможно у кого-то были кейсы по выводу проекта из такого плачевного состояния в состояние проекта от работы с которым не хочется уволится.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если у вас нет феи крестной, то очевидно что покрыть достаточно быстро тестами проект - нужно либо больше людей либо больше времени если количество людей неизменно.

Нужно донести до каждого разработчика важность тестов ибо как показывает практика не все понимают что это жизненно нужно.

Тут так же важно начать. Начать можно с простого - проверьте хотя бы все контроллеры на отсутствие 500-х ошибок. Делается очень просто и быстро - итерация по массиву роутов и смотрите код возвращаемый клиентом.

Для версии 3 применим, например еще вариант проверки работы сервисов, по аналогии с контроллерами. Берете из контейнера жизненно важные сервисы, дергаете публичные методы и ожидаете не 5** .  (ну для 4 и 5 он конечно же тоже применим, но с оговорками, если мы хотим использовать моки)

Так же важно, по моему мнению, выработать с коллегами принципы тестирования, чтоб никто не начал заниматься ерундой. Я в свое время занимался полной ахинеей, тестируя приватные методы в сервисах через Reflection будучи уверенным что это прям жизненно необходимо, но не понимая что если возникает такая необходимость то это проблема в архитектуре.

Конечно нет смысла рассказывать про соблюдения баланса между фанатизмом и реальным тестированием ибо это все зависит от опыта и проекта.

Однако весь мой посыл состоит в том что для того чтоб начать - нужно начать.
Если речь идет о сообществе, нужно чтоб все понимали важность данного мероприятия, главное же конечно чтоб тимлид, если есть какая либо иерархия. Так же нужно сразу же писать тесты к новому коду. Главное - делать. Культура придет чуть позже, но обязательно придет.